# Python 2.7 : Reading an excel which has a table inside a cell

Tags: python, excel, module, ms-word, openpyxl

I have this [weird excel](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=15454226257967273939) which has a Microsoft-word table inside a cell. I tried openpyxl to read this cell:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('weirdexcel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
print sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value
```

but it is not working. Can someone suggest me how to read each element of this table which is inside this excel cell? Or suggest which python module can be useful here?

**Update:**
I zipped and unzipped the excel file and find the table in *embeddings* folder as MS-Word file using below code :

```
myExcelFile = zipfile.ZipFile("weirdexcel.xlsx") 
myExcelFile.extractall("myFolder")
myExcelFile.close()
```

Now my question is how to find out that this MS-word file belongs to row which has ID *L_SpVer_1133* ? **I need to find a connection between MS-word files and their rows(which row they belong to in Excel file)** in case there are lot of rows with embedded tables in *weirdexcel.xlsx*.

Comment: Hello, what is you errror please ?

Comment: There is no error. It prints 'None'

Answer (score 1):

The Word file is not inside B2 but the worksheet itself. Currently, openpyxl does not see the file and, therefore, you cannot access it.

You can probably get at the original file by unzipping the XLSX and searching the contents for the embedded docx.

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani Editing a question after someone has given you an answer which answers the original question is not correct procedure on Stack Overflow. If Charlie's contribution answered the original question you should mark it as "the answer" by clicking the checkmark next to it. When the information in an answer leads to a new question, please post it as a new question. Stack OVerflow is not an open-ended discussion forum, but a Q & A site.